# error when trying to download PlatformIO IDE Terminal Atom text editor

Tags: atom-editor

Installing “platformio-ide-terminal@2.10.0” failed.Hide output…

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
> > prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js

```
C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=6.1.12 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.7.30611.23) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.7.30611.23) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.5.27130.2020) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1274) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2013
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2019"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "2019"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual"
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.52.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\Jo\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Jo\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.52.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020915-17412-q23qgb.5kki No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jo\.atom\.apm\_logs\2020-10-15T17_01_57_157Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hello, if you look closely at this output you can see the line `Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use` which is preceded by a message that starts `You need to install...`. I would start there, seems you need to install at least one dependency before this will run as expected.

Comment: Did you try installing the extension for ide-platformio-terminal.  are you using VS Studio or Atom?  you error message mentions VS Studio in a lot of plces... Maybe thats normal. Go to https://atom.io/packages and look for platformio-ide-terminal and load that into Atom.  Then go to extensions in Atom and turn that package on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated yet, but I think that something changed with the last update of Atom. I encourred the same error with the new version 1.52 (13 October) on Windows 10 x64. I tried to upgrade and reinstall Visual Studio but nothing changed.

All works fine with Atom version 1.51.